# Additional elements in JSON and how to handle them

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I using an API to pull property data. That data is passed to me as JSON. I pass in an address and should get back all available data for that property.

I am using code created by app.quicktype.io that takes JSON and converts it to Dart.
I can pass in the example address and get data back and then I can display it on the emulator screen.
However, I have passed in a different address which I get the JSON back but there is one additional element in the JSON and I think this causes an error.

This is the data that has the additional element and error after it has been decoded from JSON:

```
  {
    addressLine1: 711 Culberson Ave, 
    city: San Antonio, 
    state: TX, 
    zipCode: 78225, 
    formattedAddress: 711 Culberson Ave, San Antonio, TX 78225, 
    bedrooms: 2, 
    squareFootage: 1340, 
    yearBuilt: 1945, 
    county: Bexar, 
    assessorID: 09296-000-0120, // different position
    legalDescription: NCB 9296 BLK LOT 12, 
    subdivision: CONV A/S CODE, 
    ownerOccupied: true,   <<<< ADDITIONAL ELEMENT
    bathrooms: 1, 
    lotSize: 7318, 
    propertyType: Single Family, 
    lastSaleDate: 1999-12-09T00:00:00.000Z, 
    features: {
      architectureType: Contemporary, 
      cooling: true, 
      coolingType: Central, 
      exteriorType: Asbestos Shingle, 
      floorCount: 1, 
      foundationType: Pier / Post & Beam, 
      garage: true, 
      garageType: Mixed, 
      heating: true, 
      heatingType: Forced Air, 
      roofType: Asphalt, 
      roomCount: 6, 
      unitCount: 1
    }, 
    taxAssessment: {2022: {value: 179230, land: 32940, improvements: 146290}}, 
    propertyTaxes: {2022: {total: 843}}, 
    owner: {
      names: [SANTOS T ESCOBAR, SANTOS MARIA D ESCOBAR], 
      mailingAddress: {
        id: 711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225, 
        addressLine1: 711 Culberson Ave, 
        city: San Antonio, 
        state: TX, 
        zipCode: 78225
      }
    }, 
    id: 711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225, 
    longitude: -98.539988, 
    latitude: 29.382409
  }
```

This is the data after decode that displays on the screen:

```
{
    addressLine1: 5500 Grand Lake Dr, 
    city: San Antonio, 
    state: TX, 
    zipCode: 78244, 
    formattedAddress: 5500 Grand Lake Dr, San Antonio, TX 78244, 
    assessorID: 05076-103-0500, // different position
    bedrooms: 3, 
    county: Bexar, 
    legalDescription: CB 5076A BLK 3 LOT 50, 
    squareFootage: 1878, 
    subdivision: CONV A/S CODE, 
    yearBuilt: 1973, 
    bathrooms: 2, 
    lotSize: 8850, 
    propertyType: Single Family, 
    lastSaleDate: 2004-06-16T17:00:00.000Z, 
    features: {
        architectureType: Contemporary, 
        cooling: true, 
        coolingType: Central, 
        exteriorType: Wood Siding, 
        floorCount: 1, 
        foundationType: Slab / Mat / Raft, 
        garage: true, 
        garageType: Garage, 
        heating: true, 
        heatingType: Forced Air, 
        pool: true, 
        roofType: Asphalt Shingle, 
        roomCount: 5, 
        unitCount: 1
    }, 
    taxAssessment: {
        2017: {value: 134880, land: 18760, improvements: 116120}, 
        2018: {value: 126510, land: 18760, improvements: 107750}, 
        2019: {value: 135430, land: 23450, improvements: 111980}, 
        2020: {value: 142610, land: 23450, improvements: 119160}, 
        2021: {value: 163440, land: 45050, improvements: 118390}, 
        2022: {valu

    e: 197600, land: 49560, improvements: 148040}
    }, 
    propertyTaxes: {
        2017: {total: 3064}, 
        2018: {total: 2890}, 
        2019: {total: 2984}, 
        2020: {total: 3023}, 
        2021: {total: 3455}, 
        2022: {total: 4091}
    }, 
    owner: {
        names: [MICHAEL SMITH], 
        mailingAddress: {
            id: 149-Weaver-Blvd,---264,-Weaverville,-NC-28787, 
            addressLine1: 149 Weaver Blvd, 
            city: Weaverville, 
            state: NC, 
            zipCode: 28787, 
            addressLine2: # 264}
        }, 
    id: 5500-Grand-Lake-Dr,-San-Antonio,-TX-78244, 
    longitude: -98.351451, 
    latitude: 29.475953
}
```

This is the code provided by app.quicktype.io:

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetPropertyDataFromApi getDataFromApiFromJson(String jsonData) =>
    GetPropertyDataFromApi.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonData));

String getDataFromApiToJson(GetPropertyDataFromApi data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetPropertyDataFromApi {
  String type;
  Items items;

  // class constructor
  GetPropertyDataFromApi({
    required this.type,
    required this.items,
  });

  // factory constructor
  factory GetPropertyDataFromApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      GetPropertyDataFromApi(
        type: json["type"],
        items: Items.fromJson(json["items"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "items": items.toJson(),
      };
}

class Items {
  String type;
  ItemsProperties properties;

  Items({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Items(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: ItemsProperties.fromJson(json["properties"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": properties.toJson(),
      };
}

class ItemsProperties {
  AddressLine1 addressLine1;
  AddressLine1 city;
  AddressLine1 state;
  AddressLine1 zipCode;
  AddressLine1 formattedAddress;
  AddressLine1 assessorId;
  AddressLine1 bedrooms;
  AddressLine1 county;
  AddressLine1 legalDescription;
  AddressLine1 squareFootage;
  AddressLine1 subdivision;
  AddressLine1 yearBuilt;
  AddressLine1 bathrooms;
  AddressLine1 lotSize;
  AddressLine1 propertyType;
  AddressLine1 lastSaleDate;
  Features features;
  TaxAssessment taxAssessment;
  PropertyTaxes propertyTaxes;
  Owner owner;
  AddressLine1 id;
  AddressLine1 longitude;
  AddressLine1 latitude;

  ItemsProperties({
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.formattedAddress,
    required this.assessorId,
    required this.bedrooms,
    required this.county,
    required this.legalDescription,
    required this.squareFootage,
    required this.subdivision,
    required this.yearBuilt,
    required this.bathrooms,
    required this.lotSize,
    required this.propertyType,
    required this.lastSaleDate,
    required this.features,
    required this.taxAssessment,
    required this.propertyTaxes,
    required this.owner,
    required this.id,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.latitude,
  });

  factory ItemsProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ItemsProperties(
        addressLine1: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["addressLine1"] ?? ''),
        city: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["city"] ?? ''),
        state: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["state"] ?? ''),
        zipCode: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["zipCode"] ?? ''),
        formattedAddress: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["formattedAddress"] ?? ''),
        assessorId: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["assessorID"] ?? ''),
        bedrooms: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["bedrooms"] ?? ''),
        county: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["county"] ?? ''),
        legalDescription: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["legalDescription"] ?? ''),
        squareFootage: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["squareFootage"] ?? ''),
        subdivision: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["subdivision"] ?? ''),
        yearBuilt: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["yearBuilt"] ?? ''),
        bathrooms: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["bathrooms"] ?? ''),
        lotSize: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["lotSize"] ?? ''),
        propertyType: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["propertyType"] ?? ''),
        lastSaleDate: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["lastSaleDate"] ?? ''),
        features: Features.fromJson(json["features"] ?? ''),
        taxAssessment: TaxAssessment.fromJson(json["taxAssessment"] ?? ''),
        propertyTaxes: PropertyTaxes.fromJson(json["propertyTaxes"] ?? ''),
        owner: Owner.fromJson(json["owner"] ?? ''),
        id: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["id"] ?? ''),
        longitude: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["longitude"] ?? ''),
        latitude: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["latitude"] ?? ''),
    );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "addressLine1": addressLine1.toJson(),
        "city": city.toJson(),
        "state": state.toJson(),
        "zipCode": zipCode.toJson(),
        "formattedAddress": formattedAddress?.toJson(),
        "assessorID": assessorId?.toJson(),
        "bedrooms": bedrooms?.toJson(),
        "county": county?.toJson(),
        "legalDescription": legalDescription?.toJson(),
        "squareFootage": squareFootage?.toJson(),
        "subdivision": subdivision?.toJson(),
        "yearBuilt": yearBuilt?.toJson(),
        "bathrooms": bathrooms?.toJson(),
        "lotSize": lotSize?.toJson(),
        "propertyType": propertyType?.toJson(),
        "lastSaleDate": lastSaleDate?.toJson(),
        "features": features?.toJson(),
        "taxAssessment": taxAssessment?.toJson(),
        "propertyTaxes": propertyTaxes?.toJson(),
        "owner": owner?.toJson(),
        //"id": id.toJson(),
        "longitude": longitude?.toJson(),
        "latitude": latitude?.toJson(),
      };
}

class AddressLine1 {
  Type type;

  AddressLine1({
    required this.type,
  });

  factory AddressLine1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AddressLine1(
        type: typeValues.map[json["type"]]!,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": typeValues.reverse[type],
      };
}

enum Type { BOOLEAN, INTEGER, NUMBER, STRING }

final typeValues = EnumValues({
  "boolean": Type.BOOLEAN,
  "integer": Type.INTEGER,
  "number": Type.NUMBER,
  "string": Type.STRING
});

class Features {
  String type;
  Map<String, AddressLine1> properties;

  Features({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory Features.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Features(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: Map.from(json["properties"]).map((k, v) =>
            MapEntry<String, AddressLine1>(k, AddressLine1.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": Map.from(properties)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class Owner {
  String type;
  OwnerProperties properties;

  Owner({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory Owner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Owner(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: OwnerProperties.fromJson(json["properties"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": properties.toJson(),
      };
}

class OwnerProperties {
  Names names;
  MailingAddress mailingAddress;

  OwnerProperties({
    required this.names,
    required this.mailingAddress,
  });

  factory OwnerProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      OwnerProperties(
        names: Names.fromJson(json["names"]),
        mailingAddress: MailingAddress.fromJson(json["mailingAddress"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "names": names.toJson(),
        "mailingAddress": mailingAddress.toJson(),
      };
}

class MailingAddress {
  String type;
  MailingAddressProperties properties;

  MailingAddress({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory MailingAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MailingAddress(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: MailingAddressProperties.fromJson(json["properties"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": properties.toJson(),
      };
}

class MailingAddressProperties {
  AddressLine1 id;
  AddressLine1 addressLine1;
  AddressLine1 city;
  AddressLine1 state;
  AddressLine1 zipCode;

  MailingAddressProperties({
    required this.id,
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
  });

  factory MailingAddressProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      MailingAddressProperties(
        id: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["id"]),
        addressLine1: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["addressLine1"]),
        city: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["city"]),
        state: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["state"]),
        zipCode: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["zipCode"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id.toJson(),
        "addressLine1": addressLine1.toJson(),
        "city": city.toJson(),
        "state": state.toJson(),
        "zipCode": zipCode.toJson(),
      };
}

class Names {
  String type;
  AddressLine1 items;

  Names({
    required this.type,
    required this.items,
  });

  factory Names.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Names(
        type: json["type"],
        items: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["items"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "items": items.toJson(),
      };
}

class PropertyTaxes {
  String type;
  Map<String, PropertyTaxesProperty> properties;

  PropertyTaxes({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory PropertyTaxes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PropertyTaxes(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: Map.from(json["properties"]).map((k, v) =>
            MapEntry<String, PropertyTaxesProperty>(
                k, PropertyTaxesProperty.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": Map.from(properties)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class PropertyTaxesProperty {
  String type;
  PurpleProperties properties;

  PropertyTaxesProperty({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory PropertyTaxesProperty.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      PropertyTaxesProperty(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: PurpleProperties.fromJson(json["properties"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": properties.toJson(),
      };
}

class PurpleProperties {
  AddressLine1 total;

  PurpleProperties({
    required this.total,
  });

  factory PurpleProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      PurpleProperties(
        total: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["total"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "total": total.toJson(),
      };
}

class TaxAssessment {
  String type;
  Map<String, TaxAssessmentProperty> properties;

  TaxAssessment({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory TaxAssessment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TaxAssessment(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: Map.from(json["properties"]).map((k, v) =>
            MapEntry<String, TaxAssessmentProperty>(
                k, TaxAssessmentProperty.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": Map.from(properties)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class TaxAssessmentProperty {
  String type;
  FluffyProperties properties;

  TaxAssessmentProperty({
    required this.type,
    required this.properties,
  });

  factory TaxAssessmentProperty.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      TaxAssessmentProperty(
        type: json["type"],
        properties: FluffyProperties.fromJson(json["properties"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "properties": properties.toJson(),
      };
}

class FluffyProperties {
  AddressLine1 value;
  AddressLine1 land;
  AddressLine1 improvements;

  FluffyProperties({
    required this.value,
    required this.land,
    required this.improvements,
  });

  factory FluffyProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      FluffyProperties(
        value: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["value"]),
        land: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["land"]),
        improvements: AddressLine1.fromJson(json["improvements"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "value": value.toJson(),
        "land": land.toJson(),
        "improvements": improvements.toJson(),
      };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

The error I get with the JSON that has an extra element is:

```
error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

How do I work with extra elements not handled in the code or am I not understanding the error?